# How do I call a Python function when another function has been called?

Tags: python-3.x, function

I am writing a Python python program that includes two functions: `bot.say()` and `message_sent()`. I want `message_sent()` to be called every time `bot.say()` is called, in an efficient manner. How would this be achieved?

Comment: There are many ways to do such a thing. Add context to help clarify what design patterns would be appropriate. E.g. can you extend the `bot` class to override the functionality of `say`?

Answer (score 1):

One simple way would be make a function call both of them, and use that in your code instead of `bot.say()`. From the two examples you provided, assuming there's nothing else to pass in, you could do something like below.

```
def bot_message(bot):
    bot.say()
    message_sent()
```